Increase of specifying rate for addressing specific meaning in a topic
I'm asking specifically about the usage of the words probable and possible in English.
Let's look at pseudo example(wall flower) for comparing them in an abstract perspective;

I want to drink light beer tonight.

Please assume that the audience doesn't know the meaning of light in this sentence and is wish to learn it. Also, assume it refers to a lower alcohol content/volume.
I think I've two option to ask it:

Can you tell me the probable meaning of light? (I preferred)
Can you tell me the possible meanings of light? (It suggested me)

Which sentence is more appropriate for continuing a conversation in general? Because, I want to use probable identifying more abstract meaning and give chances that I don't have familiarity but, I run across possible usage more common. I don't sure about it. Does possible usage more/way more describes my intention? Does people prefer which of them in casual usage. Can I increase ambiguity with choose of probable?
Moreover, I wish to know whether people generally use or think about targeting or addressing more often in conversations, rather than focusing on probability between them? I wish to know Can we generalize more concrete tendency in general usage of English?
If we choose possible, would it be still ambiguous taste? If not, could you describe the situations where more probability probable is important and valid?

Does your native language not have the same difference in meaning? I have never heard of language mentality, as a thing.

It have but my usage makes difference, I mean my approach matter. Yeah it is weird but studying different languages, things goes thinking differently.

If you wanted to know what a speaker meant by the term light in that sentence, you would ask "What do you mean by light?" rather than asking about all possible meanings. And what have wallflowers to do with it?

I fear I cannot understand the English in your comment above. There are so many mistakes it makes it incomprehensible. Sorry.

If you asked "What are the possible meanings of the word light?" in the abstract, you are asking people to list all the meanings of the word. There are a lot of them. If you asked it in the context you described, then chances are a native English speaker would infer your meaning, but you are actually still asking them what are all the meanings of the word light.
If you asked "What is the probable meaning of light?", then I believe most people interpret that as what do you think is the most probable meaning of the word. Personally, I would normally say:

What do you think the word light means in the sentence?

We do use words to convey an estimate of probability. If I were asked "who do you think will win the US Presidential election?" If I said "Probably Kamala Harris," I mean that I think she has the highest probability of winning among all the candidates. However, that might be 40% (e.g. there are 4 plausible candidates, each with a 20% probability of winning) or it might be 80%. In this context, saying possibly would be odd, because you could say that about Donald Trump as well, or you may (wrongly) think that one of the third party candidates may win.
Apart from that, I would normally interpret the word probable as something over 50% probability, but definitely not 100% and probably less than 90%. If someone thought that there was a 90% chance that something would happen, they'd probably say something like "Harris is sure to win the election." If the election is treated as a random event, then 90% probability means that one in ten tries on average, someone else will win.
I would interpret the word possible as denoting a probability less than 50%, but definitely more than 0%. The issue is that people don't always think systematically about probability and word use. This question asked about the sentence

newly available oil might potentially create a drop in prices

Might and potentially each convey some probabilistic uncertainty. Did the writer mean "might potentially" as an amplifier, meaning that it's possible but more unlikely than if they said "might"? This is not a great sentence from an English perspective. Furthermore, this was in a business context, when the probability may matter to the reader. It would have been better to say:

Newly available oil could possibly lower oil prices, although we think this is less likely than not.


I edited the question to get concrete things.


Which sentence is more appropriate for continuing a conversation in general?

I understand your phrase "in a conversation in general" to refer to a conversation between two people who are not specialists in some area but simply people who, by an accident of fate, are chatting, like people sitting in adjacent seats on an airplane are known to do.
In that sense of "conversation", neither is more appropriate, since both phrases, probable meaning and possible meanings, are rather wooden constructions, not  really the sort of thing you'd say when chatting.  How often do people chat about language, after all?  Though you might talk about a weird beer-marketing phrase you'd learned while visiting the US:

What do you think "light beer" might mean in the US?

The modal "might mean" is surely how most native speakers would express that idea, preferring it over "What do you suppose is the probable meaning of 'light beer' in the US?"
If you're talking to a German with knowledge of English but who hadn't been to the US, they might say "A pale lager?"
